# kml network link styling

Tags: kml, google-earth, kml-network-link

I have a kml network link (parent) that loads a second kml file (child) that contains a set of polygons.  Currently the style of the polygons is set to a url within the child kml file.  I would like to be able to modify the style of the polygons at the level of the network link, without having to change the childs xml.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Loading styles with a network link doesn't work. Well, it works, but
probably not as intended. Remove the network link in your.kml,
and instead of `<styleUrl>#Style17</styleUrl>` use
`<styleUrl>styledefs.kml#Style17</styleUrl>`. You might need to use an
absolute URI to reference **styledefs.kml** depending on how your.kml is
normally accessed.